# How to get current progress of a video of youtube api

Tags: javascript, angular, youtube-api

I(m using youtube player API and I want to put a listener on the video progress.

What I have now is this:

```
this.interval = setInterval(function(){ console.log(window.player.getCurrentTime()); }, 1000);
```

But getCurrentTime isn't being recognized as a function, how can I access the progress of a video?

Comment: We need the whole page HTML+JS. Your code should work.
What is the output for `console.log(player)`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to get the element first:

```
ytplayer = document.getElementById("movie_player");
ytplayer.getCurrentTime();
```